# Update list view from 2nd activity | Android

Tags: android, listview

hi i have RecyclerView in that when user click on one row i am making changes in ui and updating view now i want when user click one one icon of that row it opening 2nd activity in that i am passing object of that position . and on 2nd activity if tick it  i am not able to update view of that RecyclerView .. any way ? ya by doing static arreylist i can do it but cant do static as there is some problem .. part form static other way

```
 icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent n = new Intent(mContext, PlayerInfo.class);
                Players mData = (Players) v.getTag();

                ((Activity) mContext).startActivityForResult(n, 1111);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

As you code shows,you can start second activity by call `startActivityForResult` and pass your data to it.
when data changed in 2nd activity,you save the new data in one object and when the activity finishes,you pass it to first activity,and you also need to add some code to handle the new object from 2nd activity in `onActivityResult`,just copy data to your old data for specific position.